# Making NCrunch run unit test with [ignore] attribute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, ncrunch

I have a unit test that is marked with the [ignore] attribute, and therefore NCrunch does not run it.
However, it would like to be able to run it manually.
With Resharper it is possible to manually run the test eventhough the [ignore] attribute is added.

Is this possible with NCrunch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, but there is a workaround

I asked on the NCrunch forum, the answer can be seen here: http://forum.ncrunch.net/yaf_postst987_Making-NCrunch-run-unit-test-with--ignore--attribute.aspx
I fixed it by adding the attribute [Category("Ignore")] to my tests and in NCrunch -> Set Engine Mode -> Customise engine mode -> select the engine mode you use -> set settings like this [image]